# Jquery each function not implemented correctly

Tags: jquery, function, animation, jquery-animate, each

I'm trying to write a function that finds all elements with the .ipad class and runs this auto scrolling animation on each element separately. I have it working when there is only one .ipad element on the page, but when there are multiple it gets confused. I'm wondering if there is a way to set it up to use the function on each instance. This is what I have so far, please excuse my noobish code, I don't know what I'm doing! Everything aside from the $.each($(".ipad") function is working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.each($(".ipad"), function(){

    function scroll() {
      $(this).children("span").animate({
        scrollTop: amount
      }, 1000, 'swing',function() {
        if($(this).children("span").scrollTop() + $(this).children("span").innerHeight() >= $(this).children("span")[0].scrollHeight) {
          amount = '0';
        } else {
          amount = height;
        }
        scroll();
      });
    }     

    var height = '+=' + (Math.ceil(($(this).children("span")[0].scrollHeight - $(this).children("span").innerHeight()) / 15));
    var amount = '0';
    scroll();


    $(this).hover(function() {
      $(this).children("span").stop();
    }, function() {
      amount = height;
      scroll();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` I do not think that is what you think it is.

Comment: I try to explain simply, when you are using `$(this)` the value will change depend where you are, if you want to use that element of the beginning you can declare it as follow `var _this = $(this) ` ...then use it later.

Comment: That worked, thanks!